# 19 reviewed but queue says I've done 20

Tags: support, review-queues

I've done 19 reviews today, as shown from here:

> [image]

The stats even say I've done 19:

> [image]

But, I'm greeted with the limiter:

> [image]

What's going on? I don't think is this caching or anything.

Comment: Maybe the list does not include audits?

Comment: @RetoKoradi That's what I was thinking too, but audits show up in the history. [Clicky](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YhagX.png) and [audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6415614), they also count as a [review in stats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NMZG7.png).

Comment: Ok, it was worth a shot... I knew they counted for badges, etc, but wasn't sure if they were in that review list.

Comment: [OBOE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error "off-by-one error")?

Comment: 4 reviews in one minute? wow

Comment: @LazyNinja I only delete the really nasty ones, [Clicky](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9YaGz.png). I also do the review in bursts, where I open multiple tabs and cycle through them via alt-tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to the 19 review tasks you see, you also reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6411266), but your vote was invalidated (deleted) by a scheduled task, because the review was completed in the same second as [this other review of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6411269). Think about that for a <strike>second</strike> minute. This is why it's not shown in your review history.

Comment: So...race condition?

Comment: No, review quality control!

Comment: So, then, why does it get invalidated? If this is supposed to happen, can you at least fix the visual discrepancy that makes it look like there is a bug in the system?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi, the count is there, just not the entry. Maybe they could put a place holder for deleted reviews, but why? (Not a rhetorical question)

Comment: @Brian he would have known it was deleted, at the very least. Might be useful for reviewers to keep on top of when and why their work is deleted.